# Refreshing IFileDialog view

Tags: filter

We need to alter the selected file type filter in an active Vista/Win7 Open File dialog from IFileDialogControlEvents::OnButtonClicked. IFileDialog::SetFileTypeIndex updates the text in the combo box, but the list of items is not refreshed, which means that the items no longer reflect what's in the "Files of Type" combo box.

We've tried various ways to refresh the view, without success. Does anyone have a technique to do this?

One possible clue: The view isn't refreshed even if you manually click the Refresh button, which leads us to believe that maybe an internal value in the common dialog isn't updated by IFileDialog::SetFileTypeIndex. Is there something else we need to do?

**Update:** It turns out that a subsequent call to IFileDialog::GetFileTypeIndex doesn't return the index that we just set using SetFileTypeIndex, even though the combo box is showing the correct filter. This makes me think even more that there is some internal value in IFileDialog that doesn't get updated by SetFileTypeIndex if the dialog is already open.

**Update:**
This is a Windows bug. See workaround code below.

Comment: Can you post min sample the repro this behavior?

Comment: Shay, any use of IFileDialog::SetFileTypeIndex after the dialog has opened will cause this behavior. It updates the filter displayed in the control, but it doesn't update the index number returned by GetFileTypeIndex, and it doesn't refresh the display. MS has confirmed this to be a bug in Vista and Win7 RTM. See workaround code below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has confirmed this as a bug in Vista and Windows 7 RTM. Here is a workaround provided by MS. In our case, we want to set the file type filter to `*.*`. This code puts `*.*` in the file name edit, which resets the filter and refreshes the view. (I haven't investigated what happens if you try to set a different filter using *.doc or something similar.)

```
if (SUCCEEDED(pFileDialog->SetFileName(L""))
 && SUCCEEDED(pFileDialog->SetFileName(L"*.*")))
{
    IOleWindow *pOleWindow;
    if (SUCCEEDED(pFileDialog->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&pOleWindow))))
    {
        HWND hwnd;
        if (SUCCEEDED(pOleWindow->GetWindow(&hwnd)))
        {
            PostMessage(hwnd, WM_COMMAND, IDOK, 0);
        }
        pOleWindow->Release();
    }
}
```

(The code sets the filename twice to get around some optimization that the Windows code would perform if the filename edit already contains `*.*`.)

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide your CFD code? It works fine for me. Is this what you're trying to do?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
    IFileDialog *pfd = NULL;
    HRESULT hr = CoInitialize(NULL);

    if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
    {
        hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_FileOpenDialog, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IID_PPV_ARGS(&pfd));
        if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
        {
            COMDLG_FILTERSPEC rgSpec[] = 
            {
                {L"Text Documents (*.txt)", L"*.txt"},
                {L"All Files (*.*)", L"*.*"}
            };
            hr = pfd->SetFileTypes(ARRAYSIZE(rgSpec), rgSpec);
            if (SUCCEEDED(hr))
            {
                UINT ix;
                pfd->Show(NULL);
                pfd->SetFileTypeIndex(2);
                pfd->Show(NULL);
                pfd->GetFileTypeIndex(&ix);
                printf("%d\n", ix);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Chinh, sorry, I see that I wasn't completely clear. We need to change the index while the dialog is onscreen, from IFileDialogControlEvents::OnButtonClicked. I've updated the question to clarify this.